# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el orden las letras de una columna en SQL Server con transposición simple?

Tags: sql-server, seguridad

Tengo una tabla en SQL Server llamada **departamentos**, con los campos: id_departamento y nombre y quiero cambiar el orden de los datos del campo **nombre** con **Transposición simple**. Pero no encuentro buena información que me ayude. Un saludo, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo encontrado en [este artículo](https://unamcriptografia.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/transposicion-simple/), se podría obtener usando una [tabla de números](https://geeks.ms/lmblanco/2014/09/01/creacin-de-tablas-numricas-auxiliares-tally-tables-1/) para recorrer la cadena y poder reacomodar los caracteres. Dependiendo si quieres conservar solo las letras o toda la cadena, puedes utilizar un código un poco distinto.

```
DECLARE @String varchar(8000) = '¡Juventud, divino tesoro, ya te vas para no volver!';

--Conservar toda la cadena
WITH 
E(n) AS(  -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas (suficiente para varchar(8000))
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS( 
    SELECT TOP( LEN(ISNULL(@String, ''))) --limitamos el número de filas
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n --asignamos números a cada fila
    FROM E4
)
SELECT ( 
        SELECT SUBSTRING( @String, n, 1) 
        FROM cteTally
        ORDER BY (n+1)%2, --Se ordena primero los nones y luego los pares
                 n  --Se conserva el orden de la cadena
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS CadenaTranspuesta; --Esta parte concatena el resultado en una sola cadena

--Conservar solo las letras
WITH 
E(n) AS(  -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas (suficiente para varchar(8000))
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP( LEN(ISNULL(@String, ''))) --limitamos el número de filas
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n --asignamos números a cada fila
    FROM E4
),
cteTrans AS(
    SELECT n,
            (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))+1)%2 Orden, --Generamos una nueva numeración porque estamos eliminando caracteres de la cadena
            SUBSTRING( @String, n, 1) Letras
    FROM cteTally
    WHERE SUBSTRING( @String, n, 1) LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%' --Nos aseguramos que sean solo letras 
)
SELECT ( 
        SELECT UPPER(Letras)
        FROM cteTrans
        ORDER BY Orden, n
        FOR XML PATH('') --Esta parte concatena el resultado en una sola cadena. Se mantiene simple porque solo hay letras
        ) AS CadenaTranspuesta;
```

Pero obviamente, si vas a crear un cifrado tan frágil, es bueno tener también el código para descifrarlo.

```
DECLARE @String varchar(8000) = 'EHMRDVTUIEDLOADDVNILOBEEIRBOSEENROAIC';

WITH 
E(n) AS(  -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas (suficiente para varchar(8000))
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP( LEN(ISNULL(@String, ''))) --limitamos el número de filas
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n --asignamos números a cada fila
    FROM E4
), 
cteGrupos AS(
    SELECT  n,
            NTILE(2) OVER( ORDER BY n) grupo, --Dividimos la cadena en 2
            SUBSTRING( @String, n, 1) Letra
    FROM cteTally
),
cteLetras AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grupo ORDER BY n) n, --Asignamos un orden dentro de cada grupo
            grupo,
            Letra
    FROM cteGrupos        
)
SELECT ( SELECT Letra + ''
        FROM cteLetras
        ORDER BY n, grupo
        FOR XML PATH('')); --Concatenamos todo. Esto puede requerir que se agregue la función de XML value en caso de incluir caracteres especiales.
```

Pero la solución no sería útil a menos de que la puedas convertir en una función que te permita aplicarla a múltiples valores a la vez. Eso se hace de forma sencilla como en este ejemplo:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TransposicionSimple(
    @String varchar(8000)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS(  -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas (suficiente para varchar(8000))
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS( 
    SELECT TOP( LEN(ISNULL(@String, ''))) --limitamos el número de filas
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n --asignamos números a cada fila
    FROM E4
)
SELECT ( 
        SELECT SUBSTRING( @String, n, 1) 
        FROM cteTally
        ORDER BY (n+1)%2, --Se ordena primero los nones y luego los pares
                 n  --Se conserva el orden de la cadena
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS CadenaTranspuesta; --Esta parte concatena el resultado en una sola cadena
```

Y teniendo la función, se llama usando `APPLY`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('Esto es una prueba'),
            ('Las cadenas representan tu tabla'),
            ('Son solo ejemplos para Stackoverflow'))x(cadena)
CROSS APPLY dbo.TransposicionSimple(x.cadena) ts;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias estuve moviendo algunas cosas y si me ha servido.